# Is @@Trancount needed when naming a transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm calling a stored procedure from my code. Before calling the stored procedure, I'm checking if the connection is open, and if not, I open the connection.

The stored procedure has the following body:

```
begin try
  begin tran mytran;

  --do inserts here into my table

  commit tran mytran;

  --return id''s of inserted records
  select id from mytable;
end try
begin catch
  rollback tran mytran;
  throw;
end catch;
```

The transaction is explicitly started in the stored procedure. Is the above correct or should I use:

```
begin catch
  if @@trancount > 0
    rollback tran mytran;

  throw;
end catch;
```

Secondly, is the final `select id from mytable;` place correct or should it move below the `end catch` block?

Comment: Well, depends. If you want to get the insterted Id's back, put it under the `end catch`. Because, if the inserts / something else fails, you will still get the Id's back. I don't know how you handle this. But when there is a failure, it's hard to see. If you put it in the end of your block and it fails, you won't get "wrong" Id's. To your second Question: A TRY…CATCH construct catches all execution errors that have a severity higher than 10 that do not close the database connection. So I would save me twice, like you did, and place the `if @@trancount > 0` instead a instant rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest you add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to stored procedures with explicit transactions. This will ensure the transaction is rolled back following a query cancel or timeout that will otherwise prevent the catch block from executing and leave the transaction uncommitted.

The transaction name specified on the `ROLLBACK` is superfluous unless you use a savepoint. In this case with no savepoints, omit the transaction name. `ROLLBACK` without a savepoint will rollback all transactions regardless of whether a transaction name is specified according to the [SQL Server Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx).

With the `SELECT` at the end of the `TRY` block, the resultset will be returned only following successful `COMMIT`; no resultset will be returned in the event of an error.

I recommend checking @@TRANCOUNT before `ROLLBACK` so that the code will work regardless of the session XACT_ABORT setting.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Insert_MyTable
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN mytran;

  --do inserts here into my table

  COMMIT TRAN mytran;

  --return id''s of inserted records
  SELECT id FROM mytable;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
  THROW;
END CATCH;
GO
```